# Problems with keeping user logged in, with Pinterest iOS SDK

Tags: ios, pinterest

I'm using the ios SDK/PDK, and I cant figure out how to keep my users logged in. If i call the PDKClient.sharedInstance().authorized it always says false, when launching the app, even though I log in with the authenticateWithPermissions .. Its like the token isn't saved in the keychain - and I really cant fugure out why! It says in the documentation, that the authenticateWithPermissions-method should save the token in Keychain - it just doesn't seem to be doing it :-/
Anyone who can help with this issue, or have had similar problems? I've googled all around the web, and it doesn't seem like others have had the same problem, so maybe I am doing something wrong, or otherwise Pinterests SDK just isn't that popular..

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that the authenticateSilently-method had to be called every time, to get the token from the keychain :) This fixed my problem.